# check sql database connection in java

Tags: java

I am using sql server 2008. I need to check if I can establish connection using server name,port number,db name,user name and password.

Is there any simple method available?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/

Comment: > I need to check if I can establish connection So try to establish a connection. If it failed, you didn't establish the connection. If it succeeded, you did. I fail to grasp what is so mysterious about this.

Comment: "closed as not a real question by user207421, user177800"... not a real user?

Answer (score 23):

Here is the sample **JAVA** program that checks whether the connection is successfully established to DB server or not.

```
public class TestDBConnection {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String Url = "jdbc:sqlserver://serverURL;DatabaseName=DBname;user=dbUsername;Password=dbPassword";
            try {
                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                System.out.println("Trying to connect");
                Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(Url);

                System.out.println("Connection Established Successfull and the DATABASE NAME IS:"
                        + connection.getMetaData().getDatabaseProductName());
            } catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println("Unable to make connection with DB");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score -1):

Here are the steps to establish DB Connection

```
         // Step 1: Create a database "Connection" object



      Connection    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:OracleDSN;UID="your username";PWD="yourpassword"");
```

"OracleDSN" is the datasourcename you have to create

```
         // Step 2: Create a "Statement" object inside the "Connection"
      Statement   stmt = conn.createStatement();
```

Comment: Only the first part creates a connection. The second part creates a statement: not relevant to this question. None of it answers the question asked, not that it makes much sense.